# What does it mean by " the original exports object" in commonjs?

Tags: javascript, module, commonjs

I was reading [this article](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) by Axel Rauschmayer, and specifically wondering about the following sentencs:

> Node.js-style single-value exports don’t work. In Node.js, you can
>   export single values instead of objects, like this:
>       module.exports = function () { ... }
>       If you did that in module A, you wouldn’t be able to use the exported function in module B, because B’s variable a would still
>   refer to A’s original exports object.

what does it mean by "A’s original exports object"??

Comment: It's referring to the CommonJS system, not NodeJS, in that sentence, and the original exports object is the object that you attempted to overwrite when you did `module.exports = function { ... }`. In other words, in `B`, importing `A` will not import that function unless you *assign it to* a property of `module.exports` in `A`. Whereas in NodeJS, you'll get whatever value was assigned directly to `module.exports`, if any.

Comment: @squint thanks for the comments. Are there any differences between Nodejs and CommonJS in respect to `export` ? but it is written `In Node.js, you can export single values instead of objects, like this: module.exports = function () { ... } If you did that in module A, you wouldn’t be able to use the exported function in module B`

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm a little off in my comment above. It's referring to cyclical dependencies, so I think they're saying there'll be a limit on what you end up importing in that situation. So if you overwrite `module.exports` with a value in A, which imported B, which imports A, in B you won't have access to that overwritten `exports` value from A because B would have been loaded *before* the overwrite took place, so it gets the original value of `module.exports` (the original object) instead of the overwritten value.

Answer (score 0):

Each module in commonjs(node.js) exports a default `exports object` created by the module system which you can consider as an empty object (although it's not really empty).

The author called this default exports object an `original exports object`.

Comment: why this way `module.exports = function () { ... }` of exporting doesn't work??